# Getting String ZweibrÃ¼cken in java

Tags: java

Hi I am using this variable in my properties file like this ZX=Zweibrücken. 
And When I go to fetch this variable its value change and showing me this - ZweibrÃ¼cken.

Normally I am using java code to get all value from .property file.
but in that case i am getting wrong value. 
Could you please help ?

Comment: Read the file with the correct charset, or use the `\uxxxx`notation for special characters in your file .

Comment: This is String which i have to show in jsp page as it is. but before its working fine. but from last few days its not working, getting ZweibrÃ¼cken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java properties files **MUST** be encoded in ISO 8859-1, so if you have to put characters which do not belong to this encoding, you must encode them with `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` is the unicode codepoint of the character.

To create a valid properties file you should either use an editor for properties files, or encode non ascii characters in `\uXXXX` notation.

Comment: Just to add, JDK has a tool to convert property files to ISO 8859-1: native2ascii.exe